# How to iterate through only the first div JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I have the following HTML,

```
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="multiSelect active" id="lbAssistingStaff" title="Evelyn Lupardus, Jamison Hennigan, Kajal Jain, Milud De Silvaa"><span style="width: 252px;">Evelyn Lupardus, Jamison Hennigan, Kajal Jain, Milud De Silvaa</span></a>
    <div class="multiSelectOptions" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; visibility: visible; height: 150px; width: 259px; top: 30px; left: 15px;">
        <label class="selectAll">
            <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">Select All</label>
        <label class="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10307">Dovie Segerson</label>
        <label class="checked">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="14172">Kajal Jain</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10354">Lydia Nikocevic</label>
        <label class="checked">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10355">Margo Mondloch</label>
    </div>
    <div class="multiSelectOptions" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; visibility: visible; height: 150px; width: 259px;">
        <label class="selectAll">
            <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">Select All</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10307">Dovie Segerson</label>
        <label class="checked">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="14172">Kajal Jain</label>
    </div>
    <div class="multiSelectOptions" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; visibility: visible; width: 259px;">
        <label class="selectAll">
            <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">Select All</label>
        <label class="checked">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="14172">Kajal Jain</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10062">Nevada Morison</label>
    </div>
    <div class="multiSelectOptions" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; visibility: visible; height: 150px; width: 412px;">
        <label class="selectAll">
            <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">Select All</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10259">Abel Schear</label>
        <label class="checked">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10405">Adam Sandling</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10400">Alta Barba</label>
        <label class="checked">
            <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="16224">amali silva</label>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctlViewFilters$hndAssistingStaff" id="hndAssistingStaff" value="10276,10352,14172,14177,10276,10352,14172,10276,10352,14172,14172,14172,14172,14172,10276,10352,14172,10276,10352,14172">
</div>
```

which generates through the JQuery multi-select.There are separate divs with the same class name called `class="multiSelectOptions"`. Now I need to push all the checked options values to Array in only inside the first Div(top Div).which mean this,

```
<div class="multiSelectOptions" style="position: absolute; z-index: 99999; visibility: visible; height: 150px; width: 259px; top: 30px; left: 15px;">
    <label class="selectAll">
        <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">Select All</label>
    <label class="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10307">Dovie Segerson</label>
    <label class="checked">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="14172">Kajal Jain</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10354">Lydia Nikocevic</label>
    <label class="checked">
        <input type="checkbox" name="lbAssistingStaff[]" value="10355">Margo Mondloch</label>
</div>
```

I tried this,

```
$("#lbAssistingStaff").next("div").click(function (e) {
    var listboxID = "lbAssistingStaff";
    var selectedItemIDs = [];
    $('input[name="' + listboxID + '\[\]"]:checked').each(function () {
        selectedItemIDs.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

But this iterate through all the div's `name="lbAssistingStaff[]"`, According to my requirement array should have these two values (**`14172,10355`**) only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the context.

```
$('input[name="' + listboxID + '\[\]"]:checked', this)
```

This will apply the selector against the `this` which is the div you clicked.

Comment: Such easiest way, Thanks. and I have another question, above HTML in question, which is generate through the Jquery multiselect,I don't know why Jquery multiselect populate each and each time without replacing first one, top div is last generated div, I don't need other divs, how can I delete others? I think each time creating separate divs which will slow the application

Comment: This sounds like a secondary question, which you should post as a stand alone question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) within `$(this)`:

```
$("#lbAssistingStaff").next("div").click(function (e) {
    var listboxID = "lbAssistingStaff";
    var selectedItemIDs = [];
    $(this).find('input[name="' + listboxID + '\[\]"]:checked').each(function () {
    // ^^^^^^^^^
        selectedItemIDs.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

---

Side note: jQuery offers a [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) function you can use instead of creating the array and then pushing to it:

```
var selectedItemIDs = $(this).find('input[name="' + listboxID + '\[\]"]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value; // No need to wrap it just to get the value
}).get();
```

Don't forget the [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) at the end, or you'll get a jQuery object instead of a true array.

Comment: Thank ypu @T.J. Crowder and I have another question, above HTML in question, which is generate through the Jquery multiselect,I don't know why Jquery multiselect populate each and each time without replacing first one, top div is last generated div, I don't need other divs, how can I delete others? I think each time creating separate divs which will slow the application

Comment: @Sachith - Something like `$("#lbAssistingStaff").siblings(".multiSelectOptions").slice(1).remove();` should do it. That finds the `id="lbAssistingStaff"` element, finds all of its sibling elements that have the class `multiSelectOptions`, selects only the ones that aren't the first one via [`slice`](https://api.query.com/slice/), then removes them.